# GIT - split a skeleton (master) into two different projects

Tags: git

I already searched around, but i did not found anything useful.

for example: `git clone master -b project2`

I have a base skeleton project coded in Django. Now, i would like to create two different projects, that will have the same base skeleton.

It is possible? How can it be done?

Another question, if i make changes in the skeleton project, how can i apply automatically the same changes in the two new project.

I hope you understand my questions. I am a noob with git yet :/

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use both separate branches and separate repositories.

Say you are starting from branch `master`, in `repo1`. Now you want to create a branch `project1` and a branch `project2`. Now you can clone your `repo1` into `repo2` with `git clone`, checkout branch `project1` in `repo1` and `project2` in `repo2`. You can sync and fetch commits from each other with `git fetch`. I hope I understand your question :)

Comment: Thanks Avim. I find something about submodules, but i didn't understand the working principle. What can you say about submodules?